# I installed tailwind via yarn and can not apply the classes

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm using php storm to install tailwindcss. After installing it seems the the classes will not apply to the elements. I have tried to install numerous times and the same behavior of the install keeps occuring.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For using Tailwind CSS, there is at least three steps you should follow:

First: Install the library,

Second: Configure your template paths (using 'content' option is necessary in V3, otherwise the compiled CSS file would be empty)

Third: Add the Tailwind directives to your CSS (using @tailwind directive).

Did you followed all this steps correctly?

I suggest you read the official start guide here:

**[Get started with Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)**